# asp.net core - entity framework - System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm spending hours to understand what goes wrong with my database but can't figue it out.
On local host, everything is fine : I can insert data with dates normally.
On the published web site, I get this well known exception : 
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

when inserting date like 23/02/2020 (in dd/mm/yy) format.

- My published sql server database has the same scheme that the one in dev (created through save /restore process)
- All fields are "datetime" (and not "datetime2")
- DBCC useroptions give me what I want (dateformat => dmy) in both databases
- My views  shows dates in the right format (dd/mm/yy) when using the dev and the published web site
- In controler, when I create a row, I only do a "_contexte.SaveChange" without any C# code : the date I try to insert in the sql database is the one I put in the view
- In the published web site, when I insert a row compatible with english format (for exemple 01/02/2020), the row is created but it stores "2nd january 2020" instead of "1st February 2020"

Any help is welcome !

Comment: From the SQL exception it looks like you tried to insert DateTime object outside of that range. I guess that for some reason your application tried to insert a C# `DateTime` object with default value: the date for default `DateTime` is 0/0/00 (d/M/y).
Can u confirm what is the `DateTime` value in the published web site before inserting the data?

Comment: I think it's the good value (excepted that days and months are inverted) because in the view I see the exception "sqldate time overflow" and, in the same time, in the alert label associated to my date field, I have the error message "The value '21/05/2020' is not valid for StartDate", knowing that 21/05/2020 is the date I have manually choosen in the view

Comment: can u set up a SQL profiler just to make sure that the right value is going into db; that value might be good in your C# code, but in the way something might affect it before inserting to db

Comment: I understand what you mean. It's not as simple as I Hoped, because I haven't a SQL Server Management Studio available in the hoster, but only a myLittleTools.net. Andmin. I will probably have to make a tmp table and a stored procedure to test what is the given value, by bassing date to string converted values ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try a couple things:

- Setting the following in `StartUp.Configure` :

  ```
   var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // set your preferences
   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  ```
- Here is another way and I believe the result should be the same:

  ```
  var defaultDateCulture = "ru-RU"; // set your preferences
  var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
  ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // you can customize it
  ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

  // Configure the Localization middleware
  app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
  {
      DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
      SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
      {
          ci,
      },
      SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
      {
          ci,
      }
  });
  ```
- The last thing: I've seen this exact error `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.` on the machine where .Net Framework 5 was installed. Even a `select * from table_name` was giving this error. Removing .Net Framework 5 resolved an issue.

I hope it helps